# Odoo 8 image on xml form rotated

Tags: javascript, python, image, odoo-8, odoo

I'm using Odoo V8 and added an image widget on the XML form.
Now this image is always 90° rotated, however in windows this appears normal.
I suppose that the orignal image was taken sideways and windows auto-rotates this and Odoo takes the original orientation. I can't seem to find a way to rotate this image and upload it. I was wondering if there was a possibility to rotate this image in Odoo itself, through a JS-script maybe?

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you take a picture it is stored with some metadata, where the orientation is stored. Check [this article about the **EXIF** format on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif). So before upload the image you should rotate it physically (without the metadata about orientation) with any Photo Editing program such as Photoshop or ACDSee.

So you need some program to rotate the images. If you read [this other question](https://superuser.com/a/905603/452723) George says:

> I am pretty certain there is no way to rotate images based on EXIF info using only standard apps that come with Windows.

Anyway you can also use CSS to rotate the div that contains the images. But I think it's not the appropiate way to do it in this case

```css
div {
    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```